# Resolving NP problem with a deterministic turing machine

Tags: complexity-theory

Im studying Complexity Theory and i have a question.
What principle establishes that every NP problem can be solved by a deterministic turing machine in a exponential time ?

Comment: This is a standard proof in textbook or lecture notes on complexity theory.

Answer (score 1):

Transforming non-deterministic moves from a NDTM to deterministic moves in a DTM, needs exponential states to be explained. For example, a non-deterministic move can be done in $2$ different possibilities. Hence, the different combination of $n$ non-deterministic moves needs $2^n$ different deterministic computation path to be explained, as an instance.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider the problem of SAT:

> Given a propositional formula, determine whether it has a satisfying assignment.

SAT can be solved in exponential time by checking all possible truth assignment.

The Cook–Levin theorem shows that every problem in NP can be reduced to SAT in polynomial time, and this shows that every problem in NP can be decided deterministically in time $2^{O(n^C)}$ for some constant $C$ which depends on the problem.

Alternatively, we can think of a nondeterministic Turing machine as a deterministic Turing machine with an auxiliary input of polynomial length which tells it which computation path to choose. The original machine accepts an input if there exists an auxiliary input which causes the new machine to accept. We can generalize the exponential algorithm for SAT to this more general situation, by going over all possible auxiliary inputs. Since the auxiliary input has polynomial length, and since the deterministic machine runs in polynomial time, overall we obtain an exponential time algorithm.